# Capturing windows 2003 Virtual Server into a VM image

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2003

I want to create a virtual image of a VPS running windows 2003 server R2 eidtion. I can log into my windows-2003 system any time. Is there any software I can install on that system that can provide me a complete VM image? so that I can run that image locally on my PC using virtualbox or other softwares.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Sysinternals' Disk2VHD?
It can create a VHD image of a whole drive or specific partitions while the system is online, but you'll need somewhere to drop it.